# How to pass number of options to disable in react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using react-select to show select. I need to pass list of options to disable them.

Here is my array of options to disable:

```
["1001","1002","1003","1004"]
```

Here is render

```
isOptionDisabled(arr) {
  let fil = arr.filter(val =>
     val.value == "1002"//hardcoded for testing needs
  )
  console.log("fil", fil); //here is console I have Object
  return option => {
    console.log("fil2", fil); // here is console I have empty array fill=[]
    return option.value == ["1002"]//hardcoded for testing needs. THIS PART WORKS
  } 
}

return (
    <Select
       value={selectedOption}
       onChange={this.handleChange}
       options={options}
       isOptionDisabled={this.isOptionDisabled(props.arr)}
     />
)
```

Basically it works with hardcoded data. But when I try to use/pass filtered array it show empty value. How to compare options of select with options from my array?

Why variable fil becomes empty when I use it inside `(option) => ...` function?

Comment: Why a high order function?

Comment: @Dupocas example part of code. Issue is with this line 
    console.log("fil2", fil); // here is console I have empty array fill=[]

Answer (score 2):

From the react-select package, I think you can specify a boolean.

For example you have to do:

```
var allOpts = [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007];
var disabledOpts = [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004];

// pass a function to map
const newOpt = allOpts.map(function(o){
  let opt = {id: o};
  opt.show = disabledOpts.indexOf(o) < 0;
  return opt;
});
```

and then:

```
<Select
       value={selectedOption}
       onChange={this.handleChange}
       options={newOpt}
       isOptionDisabled={option => option.show === false}
     />
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `isOptionDisabled` takes complete options passed as argument and return is the option is disabled or not.

So you can create a new option array using your old option array in the format the `isOptionDisabled` function understands.

Also you need two functions to actually show your value in `select`, i.e. `getOptionLabel` and `getOptionValue` as below.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

let optionsArray = [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007];
let disabledArray = [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004];
optionsArray = optionsArray.map(val => disabledArray.includes(val) ? { title: val, isDisabled: true } : { title: val, isDisabled: false })

class App extends Component {

    isOptionDisabled = option => {
        return option.isDisabled;
    }

    getOptionLabel = option => option.title;

    getOptionValue = option => option.title;

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Select
              options={optionsArray}
              getOptionLabel={this.getOptionLabel}
              getOptionValue={this.getOptionValue}
              isOptionDisabled={this.isOptionDisabled.bind(this)}
            />
        </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```